# Java method reference to no argument method as consumer

Tags: java, lambda, consumer, method-reference

While checking out some details of Java's method references I wondered how the following piece of code works:

```
public class MethodRef {
    private static class MyProcessor {
        private int value;

        MyProcessor(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        } 

        void process() {
            System.out.println(value);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stream.of(1,2,3,4)
        .map(MyProcessor::new)
        .forEach(MyProcessor::process);
    }
}
```

The `MyProcessor::new` should act as a Function creating `MyProcessor` instances with its provided one-param constructor.

However, I wonder why `MyProcessor::process` can be used as a `Consumer` though its implementation doesn't take any argument.

My take at this:

The `.map()` returns a Stream of `MyProcessor` instances. As `process` is a non-static method, the compiler will convert the `.forEach(MyProcessor::process)` to something like `.forEach(p -> p.process())`, which should be a valid `Consumer`.

Comment: Your "take at this" is quite right.

Comment: I was not aware you could do something like `::new` in java. Do you know what this feature is called? I would like to learn more about it.

Comment: Its literally called "method references". Added with Java 8.